# Creating FeatureCollection from imported assets in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: shapefile, import, google-earth-engine, iteration

I have imported several shapefiles as a Fusion Table in Google EE. My goal is to calculate the amount of forest loss (from [Hansen et al](https://code.earthengine.google.com/dataset/UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015)) and the [MODIS VCF](https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#detail/MODIS%2F051%2FMOD44B) (percentage tree cover) for each shapefile, and later do a comparison to see if the two data sets are in agreement. To do so, I want be able to iterate through each shapefile and calculate the amount of pixels of forest loss/VCF per year.

I have one script for the Hansen data set and one for the MODIS VCF, but both are not working ideally for me.

**MODIS VCF:**

```
//Import fusion table containing the 8 shapefiles
// Without the ee.filter.eq, I only get a single graph where I don't know for sure from which area it is showing

var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1Sh6L7D67LeaMWvs9eYnfOQmp-ReR6oQEmWCi2trX')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", '2')) 
    ;

var aggregate_array = fc.aggregate_array('name');
print(aggregate_array, fc);

var region = fc;
Map.addLayer(region);

// Zoom to location.
Map.centerObject(region, 7);

// Choose date of interest
var StartDate = '2000-03-05';
var EndDate = '2015-03-07';

// Add the satellite time series
var modisVCF = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/051/MOD44B')
    .select('Percent_Tree_Cover')
    .filterDate(StartDate,EndDate)
    .filterBounds(region);

print (modisVCF);

// Let's make a chart!
var TimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: modisVCF,
    regions: region,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    band: 'Percent_Tree_Cover',
    scale: 5000,
    xProperty: 'system:time_start',
    seriesProperty: 'label'
  }).setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Percentage Tree Cover',
      vAxis: {title: 'Tree Cover (%)'},
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 1,
    });

print(TimeSeries);
```

My issue with this piece of code is that it only gives me the data I want one location at a time. How can I plot all locations in one graph?

**Hansen Global Forest Change:**

Which I originally got from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272036/exporting-loss-pixels-from-hansen-data-global-forest-change-dataset-on-google-ea?rq=1)

```
// Import fusion table
var region = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1Sh6L7D67LeaMWvs9eYnfOQmp-ReR6oQEmWCi2trX');

// Load Hansen tree cover
var gfcImage = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');
var lossYear = gfcImage.select('lossyear');

var scale = 100;

//Sequence of years for which we need to extract loss
var years = ee.List.sequence(1, 14); //2001 to 2014

Map.centerObject(region);

var addVar = function(feature) {

  // function to iterate over the sequence of years
  var addVarYear = function(year, feat) {
    // cast var
    year = ee.Number(year).toInt();
    feat = ee.Feature(feat);

    // actual year to write as property
    var actual_year = ee.Number(2000).add(year);
    var year_str = actual_year.format();

    // filter year:
    // 1st: get mask
    var filter = lossYear.eq(year);
    // 2nd: apply mask
    var filtered = gfcImage.updateMask(filter);

    // reduce variables over the feature
    var reduc = filtered.reduceRegion({
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      scale: scale
    });

    // get results
    var loss = ee.Number(reduc.get('loss'));

    // set names
    var nameloss = ee.String("loss").cat(year_str);

     // alternative 2: always set property
    // set properties to the feature
    return feat.set(nameloss, loss.format());
  };

  // iterate over the sequence
  var newfeat = ee.Feature(years.iterate(addVarYear, feature));

  // return feature with new properties
  return newfeat;
};

var lossstack = region.map(addVar);
print(lossstack);

Map.addLayer(lossstack, {}, "lossstack")

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: lossstack,
  description: 'ForestLoss',
  folder: "Google EE results",
  fileFormat: "CSV",
  });
```

In this piece of code, I am able to get all of the forest loss per year per location. However I could use some help in making a more elegant CSV file. Can I choose not to include the geometry somehow?

Here is what the CSV file looks like:
[image: CSV file of forest loss]

Comment: Can you share the assets and your code? When you import the shapefile asset you usually import it as a FeatureCollection - those can be merged. So without the code im uncertain what your issue is.